# Adding a control in Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to add a control in DataGridView? Using Button event. For example i want to create a new a row and column in DataGridView, this i want to happen through button control. How can i do it?
I am using C#.net and MS-Access.

Comment: Adding a control does NOT necessarily mean simply adding a row/column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a piece of code for adding a control into the gridview.

private void addNewRowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

```
       this.DataGridViewIssue.Rows.Add();//This line will add a new button contol into the grid 
   }

   private void deleteRowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (this.DataGridViewIssue.SelectedRows.Count > 0 &&
           this.DataGridViewIssue.SelectedRows[0].Index !=
           this.DataGridViewIssue.Rows.Count - 1)
       {
           this.DataGridViewIssue.Rows.RemoveAt(
               this.DataGridViewIssue.SelectedRows[0].Index);
       }
   }

   private void SetupLayout()
   {
       this.Size = new Size(1055, 800);

       addNewRowButton.Text = "Add Row";
       addNewRowButton.Location = new Point(10, 10);
       addNewRowButton.Click += new EventHandler(addNewRowButton_Click);

       deleteRowButton.Text = "Delete Row";
       deleteRowButton.Location = new Point(100, 10);
       deleteRowButton.Click += new EventHandler(deleteRowButton_Click);

       buttonPanel.Controls.Add(addNewRowButton);
       buttonPanel.Controls.Add(deleteRowButton);
       buttonPanel.Height = 50;
       buttonPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;

       this.Controls.Add(this.buttonPanel);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't match it's title. The title asks about controls but the question is about rows and columns, I'm ignoring the title and I'm assuming it's an unbound `DataGridView`.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) MSDN link shows how to add rows and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkatshfa.aspx) shows how to add columns.

Comment: yes of course, thanks a lot ho1, i hope this will help me a lot